# Using Reactive Extensions and Timers ... "For Dummies" version

Tags: .net-4.0, system.reactive, reactive-programming

Despite the patient assistance of the community [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18624167/windows-service-just-stops-no-messages-no-alerts-errors-warning-nothing), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18415558/reactive-extensions-why-does-this-exit-immediately), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18412379/what-am-i-missing-about-reactive-extension-timers) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18116506/creating-multiple-timers-with-reactive-extensions) - I fear I am no closer to true understanding.  I am trying to hammer the concepts from [IntroToRx](http://www.introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/01_WhyRx.html) into my brain, but to paraphrase King Arthur: *"this new learning befuddles me.  Explain again about the sheep's bladders and earthquakes."*  Which, to my mind, is what we might as well be talking about.

I'll dumb it down to the requirements (which have changed - .NET 4.0 being the kicker) rather than possibly going down the wrong path with my own (likely flawed) implementation:

1. I need to use .NET Framework 4.0 to write a Windows Service.
2. I need my Windows service to call a web service (WS), and pass it one of a number of URLs, but just one URL per call.
3. I need to be able to define individual intervals for each URL (1 to *n*) to call the WS. For example: I might call the WS every hour for URL1, every four hours for URL2, etc.
4. I need to be able to stop calling the web service for a particular URL if the web service returns an error for that URL.

So that's it.  From what little I understand, this is a perfect Rx scenario.  I'm pretty sure I want to create `Observable.Timer`s for the sequences, but how do I disable a timer on an error?  This is probably a `CancellationToken` waiting to happen (or would I just Complete the timer), but I just can't seem to take the examples and mush them into a solid, understandable solution.

Whaddaya say, S.O.: anyone want to take this old man by the hand and explain in small words the right way to do such nonsense?  If I haven't explained it well, or if I've left something out, I'll be happy to edit.

Thanks.

Comment: I think you'll need to break your question down into smaller pieces for people to help you with it. This is much too large for one answer, especially on a topic that has very light traffic on here (system.reactive).

Comment: How big do you expect `n` to be?

Comment: @Brandon - `n` shouldn't get to more than a hundred URL's at my wildest extreme - more likely ten or twenty will be the maximum.

Comment: Then Lee's solution is the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) I think you want to look at `Observable.Interval`. `Observable.Timer` is a single value sequence, in contrast `Observable.Interval` will keep producing values at the given interval. If for each item/url this polling period is constant, then this is probably what you want.

2) You can mix `IEnumerable` (URLs) and `IObservable` (polling event) sequences together.

3) An error will terminate a sequence. You can leverage this by projecting (`Select`) a value from a sequence to the output of a WebRequest. If the WebRequest fails, the sequence will `OnError` with the exception being propagated as the OnError payload.

Moving through this slowly then;

- we want to take a list of URL/Period pairs,
- poll the URL at its given period,
- stop polling a URL if any call to that URL fails (and probably log it)
- stop polling if the windows service is stopped

Lets first just deal with a single URL to poll

```
protected override void OnStart(string [] args)
{
    var resource = new {Url="http://www.bing.com", Period=TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3)};

    var pollingSequence =  Observable.Interval(resource.Period)
                                     .Select(_=>Request(resource.Url));
    var subscription = pollingSequence.Subscribe(
            response=>Log(response),
            ex=>Log(ex)
        ));
    _subscriptions = new CompositeDisposable(subscription);
}

protected override void OnStop()
{
    Dispose();
}

private bool Request(string url)
{
    //TODO:
}

public void Dispose()
{
    _subscriptions.Dispose();
}
```

To visualize this, we can use a "Marble diagram". Here each char space represents 1 minute. OnNext are represented as an 'o' (marble).

```
    bing    --o--o--o--o-       (every 3rd minute)
```

To be more accurate we are actually getting values through on the event (even though we ignore the value)

```
    bing    --0--1--2--3-
```

We then take each event and project it to a request so the sequence now goes to this (where 'r' represents a Response from a request)

```
    bing    --r--r--r--r-
```

If any request was to fail, the sequence would teminate e.g here the 3 request fails and we show an OnError with an 'X'

```
    bing    --r--r--X
```

Now we can extend the example to a list of resource i.e. `IEnumerable<IObservable<T>>`

```
protected override void OnStart(string [] args)
{
    var resources = new[] { 
        new {Url="http://www.bing.com", Period=TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3)},
        new {Url="http://www.google.com", Period=TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2)},
        new {Url="http://www.yahoo.com", Period=TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5)},
        new {Url="http://www.stackoverflow.com", Period=TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2)}
    };

    //The same as before, but now we create a polling sequence per resource.
    var pollingSequences = from resource in resources
                        select Observable.Interval(resource.Period)
                                            .Select(_=>Request(resource.Url));

    //Now we cant subscribe to an `IEnumerable<IObservable<T>>` *, 
    //  but we can subscribe to each sequence in it.
    // This turns our queries (IE<IO<T>>) into subscriptions (IE<IDisposable>).
    var subscriptions = pollingSequences.Select(x => 
        x.Subscribe(
            response=>Log(response),
            ex=>Log(ex)
        ));
    _subscriptions = new CompositeDisposable(subscriptions);
}
```

Here we have a service that will start calling the `Request` method (for you to implement), passing the Url at a period specified for the Url. If the Request method throws, then the Url will no longer get polled. If you stop the service, then the subscriptions are disposed and no more polling happens.

To visualize this, we can use a "Marble diagram". So we start out with a "row" for each "resource" (data in space) ie. `var resources = new[] { ...};`

```
    bing
    google
    yahoo
    SO
```

Next we consider each row to also have a sequence of polling event (data in time). From the code above (using 1 char = 1 minute)

```
    bing    --1--2--3-      (every 3rd minute)
    google  -1-2-3-4-5      (every 2nd minute)
    yahoo   ----1----2      (every 5 minutes)
    SO      -1-2-3-4-5      (every 2nd minute)
```

- You can't subscribe to `IEnumerable<IObservable<T>>`, but there are Rx methods like Concat and Merge that deal with this type of data. 
  We dont want to use these however as they flatten the sequences into a single sequence, which would mean if any failed, all polling would stop.

Comment: Lee, you're too kind.  Thank you for taking extra time to break this down for the slower kid in the class.  ;-)  Can you break down the LINQ query for pollingSequences?  I'm having trouble conceptualizing the way the `select` and `.Select()` are working together.

Comment: I have updated the sample to show working with a single resource first, and then extend that sample working with a list of resources. HTH

Comment: you're an amazing teacher.  This is fantastic, and I hope it helps the rest of the community as much as it has me.  Thanks again for this.

Comment: this code is still "falling through" and the program stops almost immediately. shouldn't the subscription to `new CompositeDisposable(subscriptions)` prevent that from happening?